# Fix (decompose) Degenerate Polygon (vertex coincides with edge)

Tags: regions, geometry, mesh, polygons

The code

```
Polygon[{{0,0},{3,0},{3,3},{1,3},{1,1},{2,2},{2,1},{0,1}}]
```

produces, according to Mathematica, a disconnected polygon with 0 area.  The vertex `{1,1}` coincides with an edge it is not incident to: it is degenerate.  Regardless, I'm looking to get a `MeshRegion` from it.  Even attempting to construct meshes from the more explicitly defined

```
Polygon[{{0,0},{3,0},{3,3},{1,3},{1,1},{0,1}}->{{1,1},{2,1},{2,2}}]
```

fails.  `PolygonDecomposition` does well for other degeneracies (i.e. handling 1-dimensional parts of shapes), but not this kind.  There may be an easier way to create meshes from path data I'm not aware of.  I want to create regions for arbitrary closed paths, possibly with coinciding vertices and edges, so manually creating the proper region is unsatisfactory (e.g.

```
RegionUnion[Polygon[{{0,0},{0,1},{2,1},{2,2},{3,3},{3,0}}],Polygon[{{1,1},{1,3},{3,3}}]]
```

).  [Detect and fix invalid polygon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181263/detect-and-fix-invalid-polygon) has outdated (and even so not applicable) solutions.  [How to decompose a self intersecting polygon into simple polygons?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172693/how-to-decompose-a-self-intersecting-polygon-into-simple-polygons) comes closer with `` Graphics`PolygonUtils`SimplePolygonPartition ``, but still outputs incomplete partitions.

Comment: `DiscretizeGraphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {0, 1}}]]` works fine.

Comment: Should I add a self answer?

Comment: I will upvote your answer if you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation,

> `PolygonDecomposition` gives a `Polygon` consisting of a union of polygons with disjoint interiors, but boundaries may overlap.

Technically, the polygon in question *has* a decomposition into interior-disjoint polygons, but it happens not to be treated that way (Mathematica's documentation seems to mean that adjacent pieces in a decomposition share edges).  Instead, its treated like

```
Polygon[{{0,0},{3,0},{3,3},{1,3},{1,.9},{2,2},{2,1},{0,1}}]
```

where the vertex `{1,.9}` is on the interior.  It turns out `CanonicalizePolygon` is unhappy with interior vertices (and coinciding vertices and edges) as well.  Turning away from polygons and towards `MeshRegion`, we find

> `MeshRegion` is typically created using functions such as `DelaunayMesh`, `DiscretizeGraphics`, and `DiscretizeRegion`.

`DiscretizeRegion` approximates shapes in steps, and apparently fills the gap entirely.  `DiscretizeGraphics`, as J.M.'s ennui reveals, succeeds.
[image: DiscretizeRegion]
[image: DiscretizeGraphics]